# How to order by a field in Azure data explorer query?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

[image]

### I want to sort by year in ascending order, is it possible in the azure data explorer?

### If possible, what is the correct syntax?

My query:

```java
{"country": "UK",
 "buildingType": "Office",
 "year": {"$gte": "2018", "$lte": "2050"}
}
```

I tried:

```java
{"country": "UK",
 "buildingType": "Office",
 "year": {"$gte": "2018", "$lte": "2050"}, $orderby: { "year" : 1 } 
}
```

Errors.
Command find failed: unknown operator: $orderby.

Also

```java
{{"country": "UK",
 "buildingType": "Office",
 "year": {"$gte": "2018", "$lte": "2050"}
}, $orderby: { "year" : 1 } 
}
```

Errors.
JSON reader was expecting a name but found '{'.

Edit: Tried sort, doesn't work
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$orderby() was deprecated in latest versions and it is no longer supported. Instead, we can user sort ().

```
sort( { "year": 1 } )
```